# Add a level 2 subsite to quick launch of its level 1 subsite

Tags: powershell, quick-launch, sub-site

How can I add a link on the quick launch of a subsite, which bring us on the level 2 subsite ?

if I do

```
$spweb = Get-SPWeb http://url:portwebapp/SiteCollection/SUBSITE1/SUBSITE2
```

Then

```
$spweb.AddToQuickLaunch
```

It doesn't work =/

I want to have links for all my **SUBSITE2**, on the quick launch of the **SUBSITE1**

Thanks,

Nico.

Comment: +1 Interesting Question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddToQuickLaunch can only be used when you create a [New-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579.aspx). To change current navigation, you need to tell SharePoint where to place your links. Like the following:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal/sites/subsite1
$qlNav = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch

$qlNewPreviousSibling = $qlNav | where { $_.Title -eq "Libraries" }
$headingNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("SUBSITE2", "")
$qlNav.Add($headingNode, $qlNewPreviousSibling)

$qlHeading = $qlNav | where { $_.Title -eq "SUBSITE2" }
$linkNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Subsite2 - Links", "/sites/subsite1/subsite2/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx")
$qlHeading.Children.AddAsLast($linkNode)
```

Reference: [Managing Quick Launch navigation in SharePoint Foundation using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/03/managing-quick-launch-navigation-in.html)

Comment: thank you again @Benny ^^ . Your link was already in my bookmarks bar :D I didn't see your response when i posted mine, sorry. But i think we both said the same thing, and we agree.

Comment: @Nico You're Welcome! That can sometimes happen while editing. Maybe we were?! Great that you managed to find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized, that I can create a title call "Subsites" on my Subsite1.
Then create a sub-title for each subsite2 (insubsite1) and call them with the name of the subsite2, and with their url.

But if someone knows a easier way to do it, as `.AddQuickLaunch` let me know !

EDIT : and btw, when i create the subsite, their is a `-AddToquickLaunch` with the `New-SPWeb` command. See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff607579.aspx).